# XPath for word following a label?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I want to extract only the number (12345) below with the help of xpath. How can I do that?

The word will always be the same but the number will change.

```
<li>word1: **12345**</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**starts-with()**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with) and [**substring-after()**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-after) as follows:

```
substring-after(//li[starts-with(.,'word1: ')][1], 'word1: ')
```

will select the first `li` in the document whose string value starts with `word1:` and return the substring after that label (`**12345**`).